Working out the appropriate level for a home-brewed spell based on the Banshee's abilities
I am working on making some home-brewed spells based on abilities from the undead. I am trying to figure out what level spell this should be. I tried to compare it to spells from the necromancy school and with spells that cause psychic damage, e.g. circle of death, synaptic static, and psychic scream.
The spell is called Wail of Mourning and it is based on the Banshee's Wail ability and Horrifying Visage. I didn't want it to be a spell that causes instant death on a failed saving throw or to cause the targets to be frightened for a whole minute, so I toned it down. I've kept the psychic damage from the scream and a reduced frightened time.

Wail of Mourning
[?]-level necromancy
Casting Time: 1 action
Range: Self (30-foot radius)
Components: V
Duration: Instantaneous
Classes: Cleric, Sorcerer, Wizard
You unleash a sorrowful wail. All other creatures within 30 feet that can hear you must make a Constitution saving throw. A creature takes 3d6 psychic damage on a failed save and is frightened until the end of its next turn. On a successful save, the creature takes half as much damage and isn't frightened.
At Higher Levels. When you cast this spell using a spell slot of [?] level or higher, the damage increases by 2d6 for each slot above the [?].

My best estimate so far is that it ought to be a 3rd-level spell?

You aren't specifying any kind of area of effect. So when you say "all creatures within range", what exactly do you mean by that? Literally all creatures within 30 feet of you (including allies)? Also, have you compared this to the "Fear" spell?

@PJRZ Hi, it is 30 feet. Some spells are written like this when the radius is from the caster. It is meant to affect all creatures in that radius -except for the caster. Does it need to say Self (30 foot radius) or something similar? I didn't want it to be Fear or the Banshee's 1 minute because it felt overpowered.

If the intention is a 30 foot sphere centered on the caster, then the convention for Range would be Self (30-foot radius). In the spell text, I would word it as "All other creatures within 30 feet of you must make..."

@DwayneTheVrock Thank you, will update it. :)

Please show your working as to why you think 3rd-level is the most appropriate.

I think that the creatures should be able to hear you to be affected by the wail

And the typical language for rider effects that do not happen on a successful save is "On a successful save, the creature takes half as much damage and isn't "

@FortTell - thanks, though it that is not a condition that needs to be met by the Banshee either, so I wouldn't want that for my homebrew. I guess the fact that it is psychic damage might suggest that. But, it does say that constructs and undead are not affected by the Banshee. So, I could include that. :)

@Senmurv The Banshee's targets need to hear her, though. In the Monster Manual the third sentence of her Wail ability goes like this: "All other [i.e. not constructs and undead, as you mentioned] creatures within 30 feet of her that can hear her must make a ... Constitution saving throw.". You can choose otherwise, of course.

Weak 2nd-level spell
Alternatives
The closest matches I found were Spray of Cards (from the Book of Many Things), Fear (PHB), Cause Fear (XGE) and Tasha's Mind Whip (TCE).

Spray of Cards (2nd-level) deals comparable damage (2d10 force, +1d10/level, slightly better type but slightly lower amount) in a 15-foot cone and blinds for a turn on a failed DEX save. DEX save is slightly better than the CON save you have, the blinded condition is a bit better than frightened, the area is smaller but more controllable.
Fear (considered very powerful for 3rd-level) targets the weaker WIS save in a 30-foot cone, the frightened condition can last up to a minute (and repeated saves can only be made out of sight of the caster), but deals no damage.
Tasha's Mind Whip (2nd-level) is single-target, but upcasting gives more targets. 3d6 psychic, targets the much weaker INT save, allows only 1 of action/BA/move on the target's next turn.
Cause Fear (1st-level) deals no damage, targets the WIS save, upcasts for more targets, and can frighten for several turns.

Comparison
Wail of Mourning deals the most damage out of these, but not by much. Its control potential is limited - 1 turn of disadvantage on enemy attacks and not letting them move closer is mediocre, especially when CON is the best save on many a monster. Still, the biggest problem is the lack of ability to exclude friends from the effect (either by a non-circle area or by allowing the caster to choose targets inside the radius).
Conclusion

This is much weaker than Fear, so not a 3rd-level.
As @Matthieu mentioned in his answer, it is better than Burning Hands, a 1st-level spell.
The closest comparison is Spray of Cards, a 2nd-level spell.

This is a 2nd-level spell, I guess. But I would be hard pressed to imagine a situation where you wander into the enemy lines alone so that everybody within 30 feet of you is an enemy.

Between 1st and 2nd level?
I couldn't find many spells comparable to this one for the classes you assigned it to, and each one I found always had something making it drastically too different to properly compare the two. The closest I could find are the following :
Rime's Binding Ice
This spell from Fizban's Treasury of Dragons is a 2nd level cone-shaped spell dealing 3d8 cold damage and reducing its targets' speed to 0, with a Constitution saving throw allowing to halve the damage and avoid the speed reduction effect. The speed reduction can either be waited out for 1 minute, or be removed by having an ally use an action to do so.
At first, it seems like a sphere would be the better option. However, while it is easier to hit many targets with the sphere, there's also a higher chance of friendly fire with the sphere, especially for a squishy caster, which would most often be away from the melee.
While it has higher damage, Rime's Binding Ice also deals one of the most commonly resisted damage types, and has the same saving throw limitations as your spell. However, its additional effect is somewhat equivalent, or maybe even slightly stronger : because it isn't a standard condition like frightened, it isn't naturally resisted by any creature, and it requires the enemy to either give up their movement or one of their actions, instead of simply giving them disadvantage and preventing them from moving closer.
As such, it seems like Rime's Binding Ice seems to be an overall stronger pick than your spell.
Burning Hands
Burning Hands is a 1st level spell, and another cone-shaped spell, although this one only has a 15-feet range. It deals 3d6 fire damage, halved on a sucessful Dexterity check.
This spell is clearly inferior to your spell : it deals the most resisted type of damage, and does not have any additional effect.
Friendly fire is a big issue here
While some spells have friendly fire as a balancing point (Fireball is a notorious example of this), this spell does not give much in terms of mitigating this. The only way to avoid or limit it would be to dive head first into the group of foes you're facing and stay away from your allies, which is the opposite of what a caster usually needs to do to stay alive.
This extreme risk is rewarded with effects that clearly outclass a level 1 spell, but are overshadowed by existing level 2 spells.
If there was an option to prevent specific targets from being affected by the spell (something done by Spirit Guardians for example), I'd feel comfortable making it a solid 2nd level spell, but in its current state, it does too much for 1st level and costs too much for 2nd level.

I would put it at a weak 3rd
My reasoning is due mostly to comparing it to the 3rd-level Fear spell.

The Fear spell affects a 30 foot cone.
This is a 30 foot area around you with the potential to hit a lot more creatures, but mitigated by the fact that it can affect allies as well, requiring you to move away from your party into the midst of your enemies to avoid friendly fire.

The Fear spell has no affect other than condition Frightened.
Your spell does psychic damage as well (rarely resisted) but the fear only lasts for the creature's next turn. So to me, these kind of cancel out.


